# Converting base 6 to decimal and vice versa in Python?

Tags: python, decimal, radix

I'm trying to convert a number from decimal to base 6 and vice versa, but it's not working. It seems that I'm not figuring out the algorithm to get it to work. Could someone please explain to me how to implement it in Python?

Here is a link([Click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129124032/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55738.html)) which gives an explanation on how to do it, but when I try to make it in Python using a while loop, but it's not working and turning out to be an infinite loop. And finally, I don't understand how I will append all the remainders together to form the final value.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this will help you more

```
def dec2hex(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    ans = ""
    while num > 0:
        ans = str(num%6) + ans
        num /= 6
    return int(ans)

def hex2dec(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    num = str(num)
    ans = int(num[0])
    for i in num[1:]:
        ans *= 6
        ans += int(i)
    return ans

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = dec2hex(78)
    b = hex2dec(a)
    print a, b
```

the output is:

```
210 78
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the name `hex` for that - normally you think of base 16 then.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is clear:

```
>>> int('42', 6)
26
```

The other way - convert a number to a base 6 representation - is trickier. There seems to be no way to do it with built-in functions and without a loop.

So one could do something like

```
def str_base(val, base):
    res = ''
    while val > 0:
        res = str(val % base) + res
        # val /= base # only valid for Py2
        val //= base # for getting integer division
    if res: return res
    return '0'
```

This gives e.g.:

```
>>> str_base(7,6)
'11'
```

Till now, it only works with bases <= 10; for the others you'd need to define an alphabet string:

```
import string
alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
```

and use it in the function like

```
res = alphabet[val % base] + res
```

It (probably) still doesn't work with negative numbers. If you need these, you have to add another bit of effort.

Comment: -glglgl  I get this when tryin 7,6 in the str_base function:
it's too long but it goes like that: 1.5e-3238e-3234.9e-3222.945 ...